# Azure Import Data Tier Application does not have Standard DB option

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I created the backup of my live Azure DB using Export option in Azure Portal. I am trying to restore this DB on my staging Azure DB using "Import Data Tier Application". The options listed under Azure DB Editions are Web and Business as shown in screenshot. However I need to create a Standard DB.

Is there a way I can create Standard Azure DB using "Import Data Tier Application"?

[image: Azure DB Editions]

Comment: Guess you may have to update the client installed in your machine. Did you try the import option available in azure portal itself ? New > Data Services > SQL Database > Import

Comment: You can also use Azure CmdLets to export / import Azure SQL databases.

Start-AzureSqlDatabaseExport and Start-AzureSqlDatabaseImport do a great job. Fast export and import Azure SQL DBs using Azure storage for backup media. You can also define the database edition, i.e. the SQL service tier. (Source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2aa9ac68-e66d-4460-b7b7-9031a6ef140e/sqlpackageexe-azure-export-error-started-few-days-ago?forum=ssdsgetstarted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was addressed in an updated version of SSMS which you can find in the link below. The SSMS is also in a new stand alone installer now:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find such option in my ssms right now. You can choose web or business and import. after importing, change the service tier from the portal to 'standard'.